# Terminal line command to erase any old installation files

Tags: system-installation, lts, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 LTS, upgraded from old LTS versions (18.04 and others).

I want to know if there is some terminal line command (or some GUI) to get a full erasing process about all those old versions installed files.

It is specially related with libraries from software we don't need today.

Is there some command to perform this?

Comment: Are you looking for something other than `sudo apt autoremove`? 

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release, it had *extended support* available via PPA (https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/_, so if you were using that `ppa-purge` is the recommended fix (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio) otherwise it maybe you just need to `sudo apt autoremove`, but it's not exactly clear what you have (errors, lazy or otherwise)

Comment: @guiverc I don't have errors, here. But, I can note some slow tasks I don't have in the other PCs. And, I have a very great issue with Audacity (I have to click on its icon a lot of times to get it runs) in this "upgraded" installation, only. So, I suspect there is something wrong, here; but I don't have any clue about what could be.

Comment: It might help if you're clear & precise, as Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release (https://ubuntustudio.org/2018/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-released/) which path did you follow?  Did you upgrade from something else other than 18.04 (*you mention LTS, last was Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS*), the all releases path? (18.04->18.10->19.04->20.04) or use of PPA on 18.04? Did you `ppa-purge` before *release-upgrade* as release notes suggested you do?  Errors also often only show in logs, crashes (inc. fails to open) may only show by .crash files being created & left in /var/crash/ ; have you looked?

Comment: @guiverc I followed all the recommend steps since 16.04 to 18.04 to 18.10 to 19.04 to 20.04. I used the ppa.purge command. I'm talking about 18.04 LTS because I used an special PPA to get any Ubuntu update at that time, like it is a real LTS version. My doubt is about some slow process, from time to time (LibreOffice, as example).

Comment: Thanks @Juan, you've done everything correctly. The command `sudo apt autoremove` from first two comments will remove any libs or packages installed no longer deemed necessary (by dependency rules unless you manually installed them),, and `sudo apt autoclean` will cause any remaining downloaded packages to be removed if they exist. I'm not aware of anything else sorry.

Comment: @ guiverc Thanks a lot! Just a question. Can we know and full erase any app/software no longer needed today (because it is deprecated and/or useless)? How?

Comment: I'm less familiar with Ubuntu Studio, so I'll use an example I'm familiar with. If you had Lubuntu 18.04 desktop installed, the editor installed was `leafpad` as it fits the LXDE desktop. On upgrade to 20.04, Lubuntu swithced to LXQt, so the editor now used is `featherpad`.  Users who used a default install before upgrade used `lubuntu-desktop` causing the new `featherpad` to be installed, and the `leafpad` package becoming an orphan (it wasn't installed by user, but to meet dependency).  It's these packages `apt autoremove` will remove.

Comment: So unless the user at some time whilst on 18.04 `sudo apt install leafpad`, getting package is already installed warning, but also flipping the package from dep.installed to user.installed, the package will be removed. Packages users installed (via command, package tool even GUI front end) will be untouched by the `autoremove` & aren't seen as depreciated/useless by the system, because the user specifically installed them (even in error).

Comment: I don't see what else I can provide.. I've written up my comments as an answer; it's not really addressing your concern I gather, but sorry, I'm not sure what else to add.  I don't know what's inside Ubuntu Studio 18.04 & 20.04 enough to pick an example, so I used one from Lubuntu 18.04 -> 20.04 (as examples with Ubuntu Studio I'd more easily find are in the 20.04 -> 20.10 upgrade cycle, you're not asking about).  I used Lubuntu as I didn't need to look anything up.

Answer (score 0):

You've done everything correctly.

The command

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

from first two comments will remove any *libs* or packages installed no longer deemed necessary (*by dependency rules unless you manually installed them*), and `sudo apt autoclean` will cause any remaining downloaded packages to be removed if they exist. I'm not aware of anything else sorry.

---  *reword due to another question*

I'm less familiar with Ubuntu Studio, so I'll use an example I'm more familiar with.

If you had Lubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop installed, the editor installed was `leafpad` as it fits the LXDE (GTK2) desktop. On upgrade to 20.04, Lubuntu switched to LXQt (Qt5), so the editor now used is `featherpad`.

Users who used a default install before upgrade used [`lubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-desktop) causing the new `featherpad` to be installed, and the `leafpad` package becoming an *orphan* (it wasn't installed by user, but to meet dependency requirement of [`lubuntu-desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lubuntu-desktop) on *bionic*).  It's these packages **`apt autoremove`** will remove.

So unless the user at some time whilst on 18.04 `sudo apt install leafpad`, getting a warning/error that the package was already installed, but also flipping the package from *installed to meet dependency* to *manually/user installed*, the package will be removed. Packages users installed (*via command, package tool even GUI front end*) will be untouched by the `autoremove` & aren't seen as depreciated/useless by the system, because the user specifically installed them (even in error).

FYI:  *This Lubuntu example is something that will occur in the future for Ubuntu Studio, as Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS was the last release to use XFCE by default, all future releases use a reduced KDE desktop.*

Comment: Key is any `sudo apt install` commands you entered that you may have ignored because they got a "*package already installed and latest*" message cause changes too, in the package you mentioned gets flagged as user-installed, and thus is not touched during normal `autoremove` cleanups.  The user is warned of this at the time, but it's often ignored (ie. read messages, as it's easier to reverse the change then & there, instead of having to look up logs to find when & why later..)